# GRANT USAGE について

Tags: mysql

**Q1.GRANT USAGE の生成タイミングについて**

・作成した覚えはありませんが自動的に作成される仕様ですか？

```
show grants for hoge@localhost;
```

> GRANT USAGE ON . TO 'hoge'@'localhost'

---

**Q2.GRANT USAGE の存在について**
・「付与されているユーザ」と「付与されていないユーザ」がいるのですが、あってもなくても良い？
・何か違いはありますか？

---

**Q3.GRANT USAGE の優先度について**
・この状態で新たに権限を付与した場合、「GRANT USAGE」の優先度は自動的に下がるのでしょうか？(明示的に削除しなくても良い？)
・hogeユーザに複数権限が付与されている場合、何が優先されるかは、どうやって決まるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1. USAGE はそのユーザーに何の権限も無いことを示します。CREATE USER しただけのユーザーがこの状態になります。

> USAGE 権限指定子は、「権限なし」を表します。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/privileges-provided.html

Q2. 上記の通り、USAGE は何も権限がないことを示しているので、ユーザーに何か権限を付与すると USAGE は表示されなくなります。

Comment: 追加する度に権限が付与されていくのかと勘違いしていました